# Как наладить строку поиска по ListView, в котором item-ы - это объекты, содержащие по 2 string-a? (А не 1 string на 1 item.)

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, android-edittext

У мен яесть ListView, в котором с в каждом item-e два TextView - шведское слово и его перевод.

Я сделал EditText для поиска theFilter, но когда набираю в нем что-то то ничего не находится
(должны оставаться совпадения, но на экране вообще не остается никаких item-ов).

В чем может быть причина и как исправить?

Вот так сделан ListView:

```
ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.switchList);
    EditText theFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchFilter);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: Started");

    ArrayList<Word> finalArray = new ArrayList<Word>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Practice.swedishPractice.size(); i++) {
        finalArray.add(new Word(Practice.swedishPractice.get(i),Practice.englishPractice.get(i)));
    }

    adapter = new CheckListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, finalArray, this);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);


    theFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            (VisaEj.this).adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

А это его адаптер (если вдруг это важно):

```
public class CheckListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> {

private static final String TAG = "CheckListAdapter";

private Context mContext;
private int mResource;
private int lastPosition = -1;

/**
 * Hold variables in a view
 */

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView swedish;
    TextView english;
}

/**
 * Default constructor for the CheckListAdapter
 * @param context
 * @param resource
 * @param objects
 */

public CheckListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Word> objects, Context mContext) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.mContext = mContext;
    mResource = resource;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    //get the word two examples
    String swedish = getItem(position).getSwedish();
    String english = getItem(position).getEnglish();

    //create the word object with two examples
    Word word = new Word(swedish, english);

    //create the view result for showing the animation
    final View result;

    //Viewholder object
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.swedish = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.english = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        result = convertView;

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        result = convertView;
    }

    Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
            (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.loading_down_anim : R.anim.loading_up_anim);
    result.startAnimation(animation);
    lastPosition = position;

    holder.swedish.setText(word.getSwedish());
    holder.english.setText(word.getEnglish());

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Аррай finalArray состоит из объектов Word, на всякий случай вот так сделан объект Word:

```
public class Word {

private String swedish;
private String english;

public Word(String swedish, String english) {
    this.swedish = swedish;
    this.english = english;
}

public String getSwedish() {
    return swedish;
}

public void setSwedish(String swedish) {
    this.swedish = swedish;
}

public String getEnglish() {
    return english;
}

public void setEnglish(String english) {
    this.english = english;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите использовать именно filter, то вам нужно реализовать Filterable в свой класс адаптера и переопределить getFilter()

```
public class CheckListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Word> implements Filterable {
    ArrayList<Word> mOriginalValues;

    public CheckListAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Word> objects, Context mContext) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mOriginalValues = objects;
        mResource = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                final ArrayList<Word> list = mOriginalValues;
                ArrayList<Word> resultList = mOriginalValues;
                if (charSequence.length() > 0) {
                    resultList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Word word : list) {
                        if (word.getEnglish().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence) || word.getSwedish().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence)) {
                            resultList.add(word);
                        }
                    }
                }
                results.values = resultList;
                results.count = resultList.size();
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                if (filterResults != null) {
                    mOriginalValues.clear();
                    mOriginalValues.addAll((ArrayList<Word>) filterResults.values);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

Выше показан пример getFilter, так же вынес ArrayList mOriginalValues

Comment: Спасибо. "Если вы хотите использовать именно filter" - а можно использовать что-то еще для этих целей? (поиск по словам в Листе)